# STM32 microcontroller typecast

Tags: c, casting, stm32

I have a question about typecasting in C language for STM32 microcontrollers.
Now I'm trying to write my own libraries for controlling peripherals of a microcontroller.
But I don't understand why and when should I use typecast like (uint32_t).

For example, for GPIO configuration register I saw the next example:

```
#define INPUT_ANALOG    ((uint32_t) 0x00)
#define INPUT_FLOATING  ((uint32_t) 0x01)
#define INPUT_PUP_PDOWN ((uint32_t) 0x02)
```

This information comes from the datasheet (print screen attached below).
Here I don't understand why typecast (uint32_t) is used and not just 0x00 or 0.

Could I use the next code for the same purpose?

```
typedef enum{
    INPUT_ANALOG = 0,
    IN_FLOATING,
    IN_PULL_UP_DOWN,
}PinConfInput_t;
```

Should I do a typecast for this code?
Could you suggest to me some study materials about typecast?
Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is `sizeof(int)` on that system?

Comment: The problem is rather theoretical as it does not make any sense to define own enum types and #defines. For the simplest STM32 uC you will have to define thousands of them. Use STM provided CMSIS definitions - they cover all bits of all peripherals (I am not writing about HAL libraries).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The typecast to `unsigned int` **or** the suffix `u`/`U` is needed for the values `0x00`, `0x01`, and `0x02` in many contexts. `0x00`, `0x01` and `0x02` by themselves are constants of type *`int`*, and there are some bit twiddling things that works dubiously on `int`s, for example when bit shifting them to the sign position!

And that would happen if you take the value 0x02 (int) and left-shift that to the bits 31:30! So,

```
0x02 << 30
```

has undefined behaviour on machines where ints are 32 bits wide, whereas

```
0x02U << 30
```

or

```
((uint32_t)0x02) << 30
```

would not.

The identifiers of the enum list are declared as ([C11 6.7.2.2p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.2p3))

> constants that have type int and may appear wherever such are permitted.

i.e. yes, they too would need the casts for those bit shifts.

---

Do note that the type of the enumeration constants in C need not be the type of the enumeration itself:

```
#include <stdio.h>


enum foo {
    bar = 42
};


int main(void) {
    printf("An enumeration constant is an %s\n",
           _Generic(bar,
                    int: "int",
                    unsigned int: "unsigned int",
                    default: "something else"));


    printf("On this implementation the enum foo is %s\n",
           _Generic((enum foo) 0,
                    int: "int",
                    unsigned int: "unsigned int",
                    default: "something else"));
}
```

On GCC this will print `int` for the enumeration constant type, and `unsigned int` for the type of `enum foo`. I.e. the constant has a different type than the actual enumeration would have.

Also, using an enumeration constant that is outside the range of an integer is a constraint violation; as `0x80000000` is not representable as an `int` on 32-bit systems, it cannot be used as an enumeration constant portably:

```
% gcc enumtest.c -std=c11 -pedantic
enumtest.c:5:11: warning: ISO C restricts enumerator values to range of ‘int’
        [-Wpedantic]
    5 |     bar = 0x80000000
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Finally, as the C standard says that the type of the enum *itself* is left to the compiler decide, some compilers might use `unsigned char` for short enums. Well, you might need a cast even there, because `unsigned char` will be promoted to a `signed int`, not `unsigned int` before arithmetic.

Comment: Most popular ARM Cortex compilers (gcc, ARM and Keil) treat enums a bit different way than C standard wants.

Comment: @P__J__ but these are not the enum *types*, they're the enumeration *constants*

Comment: it is STM32 question. no one cares about the portability especially is enums are used for the  hardware related code

Comment: @P__J__ and did you read anything that I wrote. Did you run the code under *"Do note that the type of the enumeration constants in C need not be the type of the enumeration itself:"*; what did it say?

Answer (score 1):

## `GCC`, `KEIL` and `IAR` answer only.

There are 3 most popular compilers used in the ARM Cortex programming. ARM/Keil, IAR and gcc used by more than 99% of the ARM Cottex programmers. Statistically most STM32 programmers use gcc (STM IDE uses the gcc as its compiler).
gcc is a great but non conforming C compiler and it has its own C dialect.

`gcc`:
[image]

`KEIL`
[image]

`IAR`:
Yuo need to define enum large enough to not fit an signed type. IAR uses any integer type (including `unsigned long long`) large enough to accommodate the all enum values. It automatically chooses if signed or unsigned type will be used (for example largest enum value used will be 0x80 [it is an unsigned constant] - the type will be `unsigned char`).

So if you compile your code using any of those 3 compilers and you do not have any negative values the type used will be `unsigned int` or `unsigned char` and no cast is needed

Comment: See my answer. And you need a cast if it is unsigned char.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The question is not about chars only enum types